# Is this function continuous and if so, what is its norm?

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of real polynomials on $\mathbb R.$ For $p\in \mathbb{P}$, define $\mid \mid p \mid \mid= \sup_{t\in[0,1]}\mid p(t)\mid$.

Define $\psi: \mathbb{P}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ by setting $ \psi(p)=p(\frac{1}{2})$

Is $\psi$ continuous, and if so, what is its norm?

It's easy to see that its linear, but I don't really see what 
$\sup_{\mid\mid p \mid \mid\leq 1}\mid \psi(p) \mid =\sup_{\mid \mid p \mid \mid\leq 1}\mid p(\frac{1}{2})\mid $ means.  Every time I try to transform it further, it gets less understandable for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\|p\|=1$ means that the largest value $p$ takes on the unit interval is $1$. Among all such $p$, what is the largest possible value of $p(1/2)$?

Comment: It is $1$, isn't it? 
Thanks for the explanation, it's getting clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have by definition $\|p\|\leq 1$ iff $|p(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

So we get
$$\sup_{\|p\|\leq 1}|\psi(p)|=\sup_{|p|\leq 1}|p(1/2)|= 1,$$

And the last "=" is correct because there are polynomials e.g. $p=1$ with $p(1/2)=1$ and $\|p\|\leq 1$ and $\|p\|\leq 1$ implies $p(1/2)\leq 1$.